# NSIS: How to check at compile time if an environment variable exists

Tags: nsis

```
!echo "$%MY_VAR%"
```

Prints out

> $%MY_VAR% (...\installer.nsi:46)

So the variable isn't replaced at all. Is this a bug? I'm a bit stumped here. How am I supposed to test if the variable exists? So far I thought I could use

```
!if "$%MY_VAR%" = ""
```

but that's not going to work if there is no replacement at all. The logical conclusion would be to use this:

```
!if "$%MY_VAR%" = "$%MY_VAR%"
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You last example is basically just !if 1 = 1

Comment: Not replacing the value at all is not unusual on Windows and NSIS does it because retaining a path like c:\$%foo%\bar is more important than playing with environment variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!if x = y` is actually a number test, you need to use `==` to test strings.

You need to trick the compiler to get this to work:

```
; NSIS 2+
!define DOLLAR $
!if "$%foo%" == "${DOLLAR}%foo%"
!echo "%foo% not set"
!endif

; NSIS 3+
!if "$%foo%" == "${U+24}%foo%"
!echo "%foo% not set"
!endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick test (NSIS 3.0a0 and Unicode NSIS 2.46.5, both on Windows 7 x64) and I have no problem getting the `$%ENV_VAR%` replaced. Here's how I'm testing it:

```
!if "$%MY_VAR%" != ""
    !echo "MY_VAR is set"
!else
    !warning "MY_VAR not set"
!endif
```

I take it you already double checked your environmental variable was *really* saved

Comment: And if %MY_VAR% is empty?

Comment: I don’t think there is such thing as empty environment variable in Windows