# READ THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE DURING THE COMPILE TIME IN NSIS

Tags: nsis

HI Everyone As i was working with the NSIS code, i need to get the environment variable value during the compile time, I Found this code written in somewhere But am not getting understand what does 'Foo' means. & How can we execute the below code in compile time, in my compiler Am not getting the environment variable value with the below following code, Can anybody give a brief example about where we can execute this & How it works?

Edit : As you requested i was inserting the link of Code referred from this forum "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149007/nsis-how-to-check-at-compile-time-if-an-environment-variable-exists"

; NSIS 2+

!define DOLLAR $

!if "$%foo%" == "${DOLLAR}%foo%"

!echo "%foo% not set"
!endif

; NSIS 3+

!if "$%foo%" == "${U+24}%foo%"

!echo "%foo% not set"
!endif

Comment: Are we just supposed to guess what the code is supposed to do?!

Comment: It would help if you linked to where you found this code! (I'm guessing I wrote it, either here on SO or on the NSIS forum)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As you requested i have inserted the link in the above post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code tries to check if a environment variable has been set (on the computer where the compiler is executing). If it has not been set the compiler just returns the raw string (like a batch file does). The code you found escapes the $ to check if the raw string is returned.

Foo is just a placeholder name, meaning the `%Foo%` variable. If you want to check %windir% for example, use `!if "$%windir%" == "${U+24}%windir%"`.

If you just want the value, just use `$%windir%`:

```
ReadEnvStr $0 WINDIR
MessageBox MB_OK "%windir% was $%windir% when this installer was compiled. On this machine it is $0"
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion Anders, now am able to get the environment variable at compile time.